# (active) hamburger menu not sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem making the hamburger menu sticky. So the hamburger icon is in the corner when i scroll down, but the menu stays in the same position(at the top of the page), so I have to scroll back up again to look at it. I got the code from codepen, i tried adjusting the code, but didnt figure out how.

If you want to view where i got the code from here is the link, but it is not necessary in my opinion for i only removed code that wasnt related to the hamburger menu: https://codepen.io/CopyPasteLtd/pen/BaxQeGw

See the snippet below.

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');
const navBar = document.querySelector('.nav-bar');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navBar.classList.toggle('toggle');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400&display=swap');

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e);
  background-size: 400% 400%; */
  position: relative;
}

.nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #122;
  top: 0;
  left: -25rem;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.toggle {
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.toggle-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

.toggle .line1 {
  background-color: #c91919;
  transform: scale(0.9) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(-6px, 4px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  display: none;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  background-color: #c91919;
  transform: scale(0.9) rotateZ(45deg) translate(-6px, -4px);
}

.toggle .toggle-menu {
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-list-item {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.nav-link::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.nav-link:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <div class="toggle-menu">
      <div class="line line1"></div>
      <div class="line line2"></div>
      <div class="line line3"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Clients</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: use position: fixed instead of absolute in nav-bar class. When position is absolute it is  positioned relative to some element. When position is fixed it is relative to the viewport

Answer (score 2):

Change `.nav-bar { position: absolute; }` to `.nav-bar { position: fixed; }`.

See the snippet below.

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');
const navBar = document.querySelector('.nav-bar');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navBar.classList.toggle('toggle');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400&display=swap');

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e);
  background-size: 400% 400%; */
  position: relative;
}

.nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #122;
  left: -25rem;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.toggle {
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.toggle-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

.toggle .line1 {
  background-color: #c91919;
  transform: scale(0.9) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(-6px, 4px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  display: none;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  background-color: #c91919;
  transform: scale(0.9) rotateZ(45deg) translate(-6px, -4px);
}

.toggle .toggle-menu {
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-list-item {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.nav-link::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.nav-link:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <div class="toggle-menu">
      <div class="line line1"></div>
      <div class="line line2"></div>
      <div class="line line3"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Clients</a></li>
      <li class="nav-list-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: great, thanks for the help. way less complicated than i thought it would be 